# Cannot access IIS Express from another machine

Tags: iis, firewall, windows-firewall

I can access the IIS express website fine from my local machine, either via localhost, or via its IP address. However when I try to browser to that IP address from another machine, it times out.

I have set up the correct bindings and I have run the `netsh` command. I have even tried turning the firewall off entirely on the machine running IIS Express, but it makes not difference.

I can also ping the IP address of the IIS Express machine from the second machine, so the network is definitely connected and IP traffic can flow between them.

Anyone got any other ideas what might be preventing the second machine from seeing the website?

Answer (score 0):

Helps if you turn off the right part of the firewall to test things!

I have set up the correct rules in my firewall and all now works as expected.